# Why is the bss section 4 bytes, even though there are no global/static variables?

Tags: c

Sorry for my bad English.

I know that the initialized/static variables are in the BSS section, and they exist as zero. But i have a question. Although, i made the c code without initialized/static variables, there are still 4 bytes in BSS section. Why is it?

Comment: Initialized static and global variables are normally in the `data` segment. The `bss` segment have *unintialized* global and static variables.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ...or initialized to 0.

Comment: Can you show us a minimal piece of C that exhibits this behaviour?

Comment: ...and the corresponding `map` file proving this claim.

Comment: "I know that the initialized/static variables are in the BSS section". No. _Zero-initialized_ variables resides in `.bss`, and that includes all variables with static storage duration that was not explicitly initialized by the programmer. Static storage duration variables initialized to non-zero values reside in `.data`, which is another segment. [See this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/237740/what-resides-in-the-different-memory-types-of-a-microcontroller/237759#237759).

Comment: I'm sorry. I wrote it down by mistake. I have compiled the code without uninitialized global variables and static variables, but I wonder if there are 4 bytes in the bss section.

Comment: Here's my C code.
=====
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("No uninitialized / static var\n");
    return 0;
}
======
$ readelf -S ./a
There are 31 section headers, starting at offset 0x17d4:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
 . . .
  [26] .bss              NOBITS          0804a01c 00101c 000004 00  WA  0   0  1
 . . .

Comment: Please ***edit** your question* to include code and general output.

Comment: As for your problem, building a C program involves three steps: Editing, compilation and *linking*. The last step, linking, takes the files from the compilation and links with libraries and other compiler-specific files. It might be that one static library or a compiler-specific object file contains something which is put into the BSS segment.